# Error running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run the app I get this error:

```
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the URL in the error message](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs), and add one of the listed javascript runtime gems to your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

I got it I had to install execjs gem

Comment: I installed node.js , I learned that I need to install a js runtime

Answer (score 0):

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Put it on your Gemfile.